Projectivization of an affine variety with exactly $1$ fixed point under the action of $\mathbb G_m=k^\times$
Section 9.5 Weyman - An Introduction to Quiver Representations (2017)

Often one has to omit some points of the variety in order to construct a more interesting quotient. To illustrate this, suppose that $X$ is an irreducible affine variety with a regular action of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$ with the following properties:


(1) the action has exactly one fixed point with we will denote by $0 \in X$;


(2) every other orbit has 0 in its closure.


In this case, the quotient $X / / \mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$ is just a point, which is not very interesting. A more interesting quotient can be constructed by omitting 0 .



Proposition 9.5.1. There exists a projective variety $\mathbb{P}(X)$ and a morphism of varieties $$\gamma_X: X \backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X)$$ with the following properties:



(1) for every $y \in \mathbb{P}(X), \gamma_X^{-1}(y)$ is exactly one orbit;


(2) a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}(X)$ is open (resp. closed) if and only if $\gamma_X^{-1}(A)$ is an open (resp. closed) subset of $X \backslash\{0\}$;


(3) if $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}(X)$ is an open affine subset, then $\gamma_X^{-1}(A)$ is open and affine and the restriction of $\gamma_X$ to $\gamma_X^{-1}(A) \rightarrow A$ is exactly the affine quotient of $\gamma_X^{-1}(A)$ with respect to $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$.



Proof. The $\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$-action on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ gives $\mathbb{C}[X]$ a grading $\mathbb{C}[X]=\bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}[X]_d$. There cannot be both positive and negative weights because then there would be nontrivial invariants. So without loss of generality we may assume that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is positively graded $\mathbb{C}[X]=\bigoplus_{d=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{C}[X]_d$. The projective space $\mathbb{P}(X)=\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is exactly the projective variety with the homogeneous coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[X]$. The details are left to the reader.


As you can see the coordinate ring for an affine variety is in general not generally homogeneous and graded. I dont understand how he deals with "weights" (though he doesnot define it at all). So in general with above specific setup. How can we construct $\mathbb P(X)$? Intuitively, I can feel whatever we apply to the constructions of $\mathbb P^n$ by $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ we do consider the restriction of action on $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ to $X\subset \mathbb A^{n+1}$. Can you direct me some references?

The group $\mathbb{G}_m$ acts on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (the action is induced by the action on $X$), and an action of $\mathbb{G}_m$ on a vector space $A$ is equivalent to a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on this space (with the graded component $A_d$ equal to the subspace of all $a \in A$ such that $t \cdot a = t^da$). If $A_d \ne 0$, the integer $d$ is called weight. Does this answer your question?
